# SQL function of function over window function in select statement

Tags: sql, select, subquery, common-table-expression, window-functions

Let's say I have a simple window function in my select statement:

`select AVG(salary) OVER (partition by department_id)  as avgsalary`

This is great. It adds the average department salary of the department in this particular row entry.

But what if I wanted to get the department average percentile?

How could I get the percentile of this department_id average salary within the average of *all* department_id salaries. That would give me its average salary percentile.

Is there a way to do this in the select statement or will it have to be done with a CTE or subquery approach?

Comment: What do *you* mean by "normalize"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I clarified normalize.